# Loading UITableView to a View in another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, xml-parsing, storyboard

In my storyboard file I have 2 viewcontrollers. A UITableViewController and a ViewController. 
I've completed all the needed coding for both of them. But I need to load the UITableView (and its data) inside a view in the ViewController.
Any suggestions?

Comment: if you just need a UITableView to show data and further you can do this simply by just adding UITableView in any view.
 instead of UITableViewController.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can do this by adding UItableViewController as its ChildViewController like this

```
UItableViewController*vc1 = [[test1 alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

//add to the container vc which is self    
[self addChildViewController:vc1];

 //the entry view (will be removed from it superview later by the api)
 [self.view addSubview:vc1.view];
```

Swift:

```
let tableViewVC = UITableViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)

addChildViewController(tableViewVC)
view.addSubview(tableViewVC.view)
```

Hope it will help you.